# Geometrical principle used in Fourier's paper "Theory of Heat"

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

**Below follow an extract from Fourier's paper  "THEORY OF HEAT" in which he says:**

Consider the variable state of a solid whose heat is dispersed
into air, maintained at the fixed temperature 0. Let $ω$ be an
infinitely small part of the external surface, and $μ$ a point of $ω$,
through which a normal to the surface is drawn ; different points
of this line have at the same instant different temperatures.
Let $v$ be the actual temperature of the point $μ$, taken at a
definite instant, and $w$ the corresponding temperature of a point $ν$
of the solid taken on the normal, and distant from $μ$, by an infinitely small quantity $α$. Denote by $x, y, z$ the co-ordinates of
the point $μ$, and those of the point $ν$ by $x + δx, y + δy, z + δz$ ;
let $f(x, y, z) =0$ be the known equation to the surface of the solid,
and $v = Φ(x,y,z,t)$; the general equation which ought to give the value of $v$ as a function of the four variables $x,y,z,t$.

Differentiating the equation $f(x, y, z) = 0$, we shall have:

$$mdx+ndy+pdz=0$$

$m,n,p$ being functions of $x,y,z$.

(...)

Now, it follows from the principles of geometry, that the co-ordinates $δx,δy,δz$ which fix the position of the point $ν$ of the
normal relative to the point $μ$ satisfy the following conditions:

$$pδx=mδz$$ and $$pδy=nδz$$

**My question is about the geometrical principle he make use to derive the last expressions?**

You can find the paper here: page 115-116

https://www3.nd.edu/~powers/ame.20231/fourier1878.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$m\,dx+n\,dy+p\,dz=0$$ is the equation of the tangent plane, thus $(m,n,p)$ is the direction of the surface normal, which is orthogonal to all directions in the tangent plane. As $(δx,δy,δz)$ has the same direction is has to be a multiple of the normal direction, which can also be formulated as the condition that all the $2\times2$ minors of $$\pmatrix{m&n&p\\δx&δy&δz}$$  have to be zero, which gives the cited equations.

Comment: Can you write the equations in an non matrix form? Thanks.

Comment: You mean that $\det\pmatrix{m&p\\δx&δz}=m\,δz-p\,δx$ etc.? These are just the  claimed equations. Or that from $ δx=c\,m$ and $δz=c\,p$ one can eliminate $c$ to find the same equation?

Comment: Is the second one and you do answer my question. But which is this geometrical principle? Is there a name for it?

Comment: T'is that the 2 vectors are collinear. And that the determinant of a matrix with linearily dependent vectors happens to be zero.